# Create dynamic number sequence view in redshif

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Actually I want to unnest a json array which is saved in redshift column, for this i want to generate dynamic number sequence view.

I can get the largest size of json array by using `SELECT MAX(JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(metadata)) FROM input_table` then i want to create a view like follows

```
CREATE VIEW seq_0_to_3 AS
SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL                                      
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
............
SELECT max_size_of_json_arrays
)
```

max json array size will be vary when adding new data, so how do i create a dynamic view for "n" number of rows

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough rows in the table, you can use:

```
select seqnum
from (select max(json_array_length(metadata)) over () as max_row,
             row_number() over () as seqnum
      from input_table
     ) i
where seqnum <= max_row;
```

Note that if the table is way bigger than the expected maximum size, you might want to restrict the number of rows:

```
select seqnum
from (select max(json_array_length(metadata)) over () as max_row,
             row_number() over () as seqnum
      from (select i.* from input_table limit 1000) i
     ) i
where seqnum <= max_row;
```

Or if you have a tally or calendar table, that could be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
with numbers as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TRUE)::INTEGER- 1 as ordinal
FROM <any random table name> LIMIT N
)
```

You may use this code to have that